# How can I (server side) include an html page inside an html page?

Tags: c#, html

On .NET I download a whole website page inside a page with :

```
m_oClient.DownloadString(link);
```

of course, the page already have `<html></html>`, so now I have `<html></html>` twice which make markup invalid.

I can't use an iframe (due to the X-Frame-Options policy), so is there another way on doing this?

Comment: Well what is it that you're attempting to do? You should never really try to inject 2 full websites inside one another.

Comment: I need to load the "instagram login" (which is a page loaded from a link) inside my website, but I can't use an iframe (for some reasons)

Comment: In fact from a page I call an aspx with JSONP (with jquery), which must download the instagram page! That's why I can't use an iframe: I get the X-Frame-Options DENY!

Comment: I see, does Instagram not do OAuth where you're forced to redirect to their main site for a login? That would explain why they block remote framing. (Sorry, not up to speed with Instagram)

Comment: Yes but the problem is before, not after rendering the resource with instagram API!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that vacuuming their login-page's HTML and incorporating it into your own is entirely kosher. Or would work. Consider cross-site-scripting guards and the like for any active javascript.